# Android loading images in ListView

Tags: java, android, image, listview

I am loading images from Parse.com to my listview, everything works fine, but the problem is that the images are reloading all the time as I scroll trough the listview. I am caching the images in memory, but the flashing before loading every image, every time is annoying.

I am loading my images with async task, here's the code:

```
private class loadContent extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Images");
            query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
            query.setLimit(limit);
            ob = query.find();
            for(ParseObject num : ob){
                ParseFile img = (ParseFile)num.get("img");
                PostRow test1 = new PostRow(img.getUrl().toString(), (String) num.get("username"));
                postList.add(test1);
            }
            //loadDataFromAdapter();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

What can I do to keep for example 10 images loaded in the listview at one time?

Comment: How do you download/initialize the list? inside onCreate?

Comment: The list is initializes in the OnCreate method, and the images are downloaded in the lloadContent class in the code above. And everything works fine, except that the listview is reloading my items all the time as I scroll.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into using the [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library. From their site:

- It handles ImageView recycling and download cancelation in an adapter.
- Complex image transformations with minimal memory use.
- Automatic memory and disk caching.

It is widely used for image downloading and is very easy to use.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I already use another library, Universal Image Loader. However, a few minutes ago, I was able to fix the problem.The problem was that I left too litle ram for the cache, I've changed that now, so everything works perfect.

Comment: Glad to hear that you were able to fix your problem

Answer (score 1):

Like the op suggests, using [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) would be the smarter approach.

But still, you need to use a drawable as a placeholder in order to prevent this "annoying flashing".

```
ParseFile img = (ParseFile)num.get("img");
String urlImage = img.getUrl().toString();
Picasso.with(context).load(urlImage).fit().centerCrop().placeholder(R.drawable.white_placeholder).into(imageview);
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who use Universal Image Loader, the problem was in my configuration, I had too little ram for caching. Now I've change that and everything works perfect.

```
.memoryCache(new LruMemoryCache(50 * 1024 * 1024))
            .memoryCacheSize(50 * 1024 * 1024)
```